# How can I arrange my form with html and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

The problem I have is that there is no results in the `"category"` option. I tried to use two `whiles` but that doesn't work either.

**This is my php:**

```
try{
             $sel=$pdo->prepare("Select * from
                         actors inner join cat
                         on actors.id=cat.id");

    $sel->bindColumn(1,$actors_id);
    $sel->bindColumn(2,$actors);
    $sel->bindColumn(3,$cat_id);
    $sel->bindColumn(4,$cat);
    $sel->execute();




}catch(PDOException $e){

     die("error: " . $e->getMessage());

 }
```

**And This is my html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <label for="author">Author</label>
       <Select id="author">

      //Show data from php file:

    <?php while($sel->fetch()):?>
        <?php echo "<option value='$actors_id'>$actors</option>";?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
       </Select>

       <label for="category">Category</label>

       <Select id="category">

      //Show data again from php file:

    <?php while($sel->fetch()):?>
        <?php echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat</option>";?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
       </Select>     
    </form>
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there is no info display in the "category" option.

If I change the html to something like this, it doesn't work either:

```
<Select id="author">

    <?php while($sel->fetch()):?>
        <?php echo "<option value='$actors_id'>$actors</option>";?>
       </Select>

       <label for="category">Category</label>
       <Select id="category">

        <?php echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat</option>";?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
       </Select>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: There are no results left after the first loop is complete. either you store the results in an array and loop over the array two times, or you run the query a second time between the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `while` loop fetches all rows from the PDOStatement object, so when you call `while ($sel->fetch())` a second time, it immediately returns `false`. If you want to use the results in essentially two separate loops, fetch all rows first into an array of rows, then loop over that array.  Do so with `fetchAll()` instead of binding to variables via `bindColumn()`.

In fact, I would *almost always* recommend fetching first rather than during the display logic, except for very large rowsets where the memory consumed by fetching it all at once would be taxing on your system.

```
// Get all the rows as an array
$rows = $sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASOC);

// Later loop for the items you need as many times as you need
// Each new foreach will iterate the entire $rows array from start to end
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?php echo "<option value='{$row['actors_id']}'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['actors']) . "</option>";?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<?php echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['cat']) . "</option>";?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Don't forget to call `htmlspecialchars()` on the output, to ensure it is properly encoded for HTML. I haven't done so on `cat_id,actors_id` on the assumption those are known to be integers, but if not, then you should use `htmlspecialchars($row['cat_id'], ENT_QUOTES)` to ensure the HTML attributes are correctly quoted.

Comment: Seems to me there would be more than one category per actor, e.g. a cascading sel, which in my eyes means JSON

Comment: This worked perfectly, for some reason if I put $rows=$sql->FetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); before $sql->execute(), it doesn't work. Also do you recommend strip_tags or htmlspecialchars??

Comment: You may only `fetchAll()` after calling `execute()`, or the server will have nothing to return.  `strip_tags()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are very different.  `strip_tags()` removes any full HTML tags from output while `htmlspecialchars()` correctly encodes a value like "String>substring" to "String&gt;substring" for use in HTML. `strip_tags()` would be used if you were taking input possibly including HTML but didn't want it as output. `htmlspecialchars()` is for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be cleaner in your return -

```
<?php 
$result = $sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //return an object
foreach($result as $actor) {
     echo '<option value=' . $actors->actor_id .'>'. $actor->actors .'</option>'; // note the quotes
}

?>
```

You can loop through the result as many times as you need to, without re-fetching the data.